# Does the react javascript run time is guaranteed to be started when a service is started?

Tags: android, react-native

In my app the BroadcastReceiver receives the intent and starts the service by calling "context.startForegroundService(service)". Does this start the react javascript runtime ?

The android **Application** class docs says the Application class onCreate method is called before any service is stared https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate() .

Does this mean react javascript runtime is also started before the service onCreate method is called ?

The ReactApplication class is an interface with one method https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactApplication.java. I could not find the react code that starts the javascript run time. If some one knows the source code that starts the javascript runtime please post the link. Thanks